# How can I create a button anywhere on the page that submits a form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to create a button that I can put anywhere on a page to submit a specific form. I'm interested in using Hooks and Context / Provider pattern to expose this state anywhere in the app.

Comment: Anywhere on the page? Or anywhere in your app? These are two different questions with different answers. For anywhere on the page you *could* give your html form element an id attribute, and on a `type="submit"` button add a `form` attribute matching the form id you want the button to submit. What have you tried already on your own? Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below creates a context / provider that has access to a useState hook for setting the submit function.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

export type HiddenButtonSubmitContext = {
  submit: () => void,
  setSubmitHandler: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<() => void>>
}

export const defaultSetSubmitHandler = () => () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('submit handler was never set')
}

export const SubmitContext = createContext<HiddenButtonSubmitContext>({
  submit: () => {
    throw new Error('submit not set, make surea all calls to useHiddenButton are within HiddenButtonProvider');
  },
  setSubmitHandler: defaultSetSubmitHandler()
})

export const useHiddenButton = () => useContext(SubmitContext)

export const HiddenButtonProvider: React.FC<{ children?: ReactNode | undefined }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [submit, setSubmitHandler] = useState(defaultSetSubmitHandler)
  return (
    <SubmitContext.Provider value={{submit, setSubmitHandler}}>
      {children}
    </SubmitContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const HiddenButton = () => {
  const hiddenButtonRef = useRef<any>()
  const { setSubmitHandler } = useHiddenButton()

  useEffect(() => {
    setSubmitHandler(() => () => {
      hiddenButtonRef.current.click()
    })
  }, [setSubmitHandler])
  
  return (
    <input type="submit" style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={hiddenButtonRef} />
  )
}
```

Here's the example usage:

```
const Btn = () => {
  const { submit } = useHiddenButton()
  return <button onClick={() => submit()}>hi</button>
}

export function Example () {
  return (
    <HiddenButtonProvider>
      <Btn />
      <form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('submitted')
      }}>
        <HiddenButton/>
      </form>
    </HiddenButtonProvider>
  )
}
```